# Can child elements evenly fill Grid?

Tags: qml

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a grid of elements in qml which completely and evenly fill the width and height of the grid/parent:

```
Grid {
    columns: 2
    Repeater {
        model: 4
        Rectangle {
            width: /* ??? */
            height: / * ??? */
        }
    }
}
```

I think a have to set absolute values here. Using `anchors.fill: parent` won't work, as well as something like `width: parent.width / 2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you forgot to set parent's (`Grid` element) anchors. Also you can always reference an element by it' id.

```
Grid {
    anchors.fill: parent
    columns: 2
    rows: 3
    Repeater {
        model: 6
        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width / parent.columns
            height: parent.height / parent.rows
        }
    }
}
```